# Ayuda con el error: " incompatible types in assignment of `char' to `char[1000] "'

Tags: c

Lo que quiero hacer en este programa es que el usuario ingrese un caracter que quiere reemplazar y el caracter con el cual lo quiere reemplazar. No se si esta bien la funcion donde hago la modificacion, pero el tema es el error que me marca que no se como solucionarlo, ya he probado varias cosas que se me han ocurrido pero no me ha andado!

El error es:

```
incompatible types in assignment of `char' to `char[1000]
```

```
struct modif
{ char textorig[1000];
char textmodif[1000];
int cantremp; };

char * carga (int  *) ; 
struct modif * modifica (char *, int, char, char);

int main()
{
    char *texto,caracaremp,caracderemp;
    int cantcarac,op;
    struct modif *estruc;
    texto= carga(&cantcarac);

    printf("Ingrese una de las siguientes opciones:  \n");
    printf("1-Modifica \n 2-Cuenta \n 3-Busca \n 4-Salir \n");
    scanf("%d",&op);

    if (op==1)
    { printf("Ingrese el caracter que quiere reemplazar: \n");
    scanf ("%c", &caracaremp);
    printf("Ingrese el caracter de reemplazo \n");
    scanf("%c", &caracderemp); 
    estruc= modifica(texto,cantcarac,caracaremp,caracderemp);
    printf ("El texto original es: %s", estruc->textorig);
    printf("El texto modificado es: %s", estruc->textmodif); }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
}

char * carga (int *n)
{
    char s[1000];
    printf("Ingrese el texto presione TAB y ENTER para finalizar:  \n");
    scanf ("%[^\t]",&s); 
    *n=strlen(s);
    return s; }

struct modif * modifica (char *cadena, int cc, char car, char cdr)
{
    struct modif arr;
    int cont=0;

    arr.textorig=*cadena;

    for (int i=0; i<=cc; i++)
    { if (*cadena[i]=='car')
      { *cadena[i]='cdr';
        cont=cont+1;} }
      arr.textmodif=*cadena; 
      return arr; }
```

Comment: El error es bastante auto-explicativo: intentas asignar un objeto (`char`) a un arreglo (`char[1000]`).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, hay 10 errores y 1 warning. Eso al empezar.

Comment: @Trauma haría falta saber en qué líneas están los errores, pero no voy a ponerme a compilar este código para averiguarlo :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya lo hice (el aburrimiento es muy malo). Líneas 40, 42, 50, ... tras añadir los `#include< >`. Miedo me da hacer `gcc -Wall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, los errores. En la función `carga( )`:

```
scanf( "%[^\t]", &s );
```

No puedes pasar la dirección de un arreglo. El arreglo es, en si mismo, un puntero. Debería ser `scanf( "%[^\t]", s );`.

En esa misma función, un poco mas abajo, devuelve una variable local a la función. Eso es un *comportamiento indfinido* y te dará problemas.

Luego, en `modif( )`:

```
arr.textorig = cadena;
```

Las cadenas **no** se copian así. Has de usar alguna de las funciones indicadas para ello, como `strcpy( )`, quedando `strcpy( arr.textorig, cadena );`.

```
if( cadena[i] == 'car' ) {
  cadena[i] = 'cdr';
```

No se lo que pretendes hacer así. Tanto `car` como `cdr` son caracteres. Tanto la comparaciones como las asignaciones son directas:

```
if( cadena[i] == car ) {
  cadena[i] = cdr;
```

Luego, otro intento de copiar una cadena de forma incorrecta:

```
arr.textmodif = *cadena;
```

Lo correcto seria usar una función: `strcpy( arr.textmodif, cadena );`.

Al final de esa función `modif( )`, devuelves otra vez una variable interna a la función. Lo dicho anteriormente, comportamiento indefinido.

Para poder devolver *arreglos* creados en una función, ya se te indicó en **EDITO 2** de una pregunta anterior.

[¿Cómo asignar un arreglo retornado por una funcion a un arreglo del programa principal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45675/19610)

Para devolver `struct` u otros tipos, es similar:

```
struct modif *arr = (struct modif *)malloc( sizeof( struct modif ) );
...
```

Por supuesto, al ser un puntero, es resto del código te fallará, y tendrás que adaptar las operaciones.